# Перевод числа в процент

Tags: javascript, task

Вопрос вот в чем. Есть задача и 2 переменные х и у. Эти переменные вводит вользователь и они являются процентами по условию задачи. Мой ментор дал мне "подсказку":
Числа надо переводить в проценты 
x /= 100;
y /= 100;
Я не могу понять что значат эти выражения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это означает, что число надо поделить на `100`, просто краткая запись, примерно как запись `x += 100`, что будет в расшифрованном виде выглядеть как `x = x + 100`. В вашем же случае `x = x / 100`.

Соответственно, если у вас пользователь введет где-либо на ваш запрос ввода данных, сколько процентов у вас будет содержание чего-либо в чем-либо (ну или какая там прикладная тематика вашей задачи), то ему это удобно будет ввести числами.

Но вам в расчетах удобнее и правильнее будет использовать не эти значения, а их значения, поделенные на сто. Таким образом вычислить потом проценты от чего-либо гораздо проще - например, `25%` у нас, после вычислений, окажутся числом `0,25`. Соответственно, чтобы вычислить, сколько составит `25%` от любого числа, нужно просто умножить это число на `0,25`.

В общем, школьная математика, не уверен, что нужно это объяснять тут.

Comment: Я сделал формулу,которая выводит скидку в discount процентах function getPercentages(sum, discount) {
    return sum - ((sum / 100) * discount); Где discount ,это значения х или у в зависимости от условия. Возможно ли использовать данную формулу,а не ту подсказку,которую дал мне ментор?

Comment: Ну выглядит все верно, хотя, конечно, это уже не совсем по теме вашего вопроса. В целом же, вы можете либо сначала преобразовывать свои `x` или `y` по формуле, которую вам дал ваш наставник, либо делать это преобразование уже в функции, как вы собственно это и сделали. Делать это так или иначе - пофиг, если только данные значения не используются где-либо еще, в результате чего нужно какое-то единообразие.

Comment: огромное спасибо!